# Location Search for Database

Tags: php, mysql, search, web

I am trying to set up a MySQL database for my website which will have a list of various locations. Is it possible to set up a location-based search for this list? For example, if someone searches "Albany, NY, USA" then there should be results from the nearby "New York, NY" if the database has no results from Albany.

I think a neat way to do it would be to use latitude and longitude coordinates. However, if a user enters in a random city, is there a way to acquire the geographical coordinates of that city for my website?

Also, if a user spells their query wrong, is there a neat way to still process the information?

Comment: I imagine you are going to need to incorporate some type of geolocation to achieve this.

Comment: how do You store data about nerby locations ?

Answer (score 0):

For the first option you could use a query in your php like the following:

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM (`yourtable`)
WHERE (`cityname` LIKE '%".$_POST('search')."%')"
```

This query will search with the word you typed in into the searchfield called 'search'

So for example:

```
<input type="search" name="search">
```

For the second part of your question you could use a bit more complex query for the searchterm.

So you match the first two characters for example.

If you want to search for nearby location you could use the google geolocation api to calculate the distance between two rows in your database.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/geolocation/

Answer (score 0):

I use this function to get the lat/lng of an address.

```
function buildGeocode($address_1, $address_2, $city, $state, $zip_code, $country){

    $base_url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json";

    $address = $address_1 . ' ' . $address_2 . ', ' . $city . ' ' . $state . ' ' . $zip_code . ' ' . $country;

    $request_url = $base_url . "?address=" . urlencode($address) . "&sensor=false";

    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents($request_url), true);

    return array('lat' => $data['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'], 'lng' => $data['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng']);

}
```

And this sql to get rows with in a certain distance (miles) of a lat/lng (this should be updated to use pdo or escaped properly).

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *
    FROM (SELECT location_tbl.*, ( 3959*(2*ASIN(SQRT(POW(SIN(((location_tbl.lat-" . $lat . ")*(PI()/180))/2),2)+COS(location_tbl.lat*0.017453293)*COS(" . $lat . "*0.017453293)*POW(SIN(((location_tbl.lng-" . $lng . ")*(PI()/180))/2),2)))) ) AS distance
            FROM location_tbl
        WHERE location_tbl.active = 1) AS tmp_tbl
    WHERE distance <= '" . $dis . "'
    ORDER BY distance ASC
```

Comment: You will need to modify it change the function to `buildGeocode($city, $state, $country)` and `$address = $city . ' ' . $state . ' ' . $country;` and it should work.  This is the URL its requesting http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=New+York+NY+USA&sensor=false

Comment: Thanks, got it to work! According to the license agreement, I suppose I have to display results on a map if I am going to use the Google API service...

Answer (score 0):

Because the google api does not allow using geocoding for purposes other than mapping you will have to create a table in your database with all of the cities int he US and their zip codes.  There is a great free resource available here:

http://federalgovernmentzipcodes.us/

As for the spelling of the city names, I would use jquery to create an auto complete field based on available cities in the database.  This way you will be sure that your users are always entering a item that can be looked up.